# How to convert string YYYYMM to date in hive sql

Tags: sql, string, hive, type-conversion

I have column as string in the format "yyyymm" in hive table, and i would like to convert this to date with day as first of each month. for example 202105 string i would like this to be as date "2021-05-01".

Appreciate your help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTR('YYYYMM',1,4),'-',SUBSTR('YYYYMM',5,2),'-01'))
```

You can try using the following, replace "YYYYMM" with your date value string.